# the Main method in windows phone library

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a library for windows phone 7, in a csharp file, I wrote a test method like

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
    }
```

but I cannot run this method and the "start debugging (F5)" is gray, I cannot use this tool as well.
cannot I write directly the Main method  and run it as what we do  in the .net framework?

Comment: Why you need main method in library?

Comment: If it's set as a class library then it will compile as a dll, not an exe

Comment: This is a console application, not a windows phone application.  You're way off base.  Close VS, delete your project, and go read.

Comment: @Reniuz I'm new to windows phone, I write this to test another library